# Combinatorial problem of choosing points inside an equilateral triangle without them being too close.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Determine the smallest integer $m_n$ which satisfies the following property: If $m_n$ points are chosen inside an equilateral triangle of sides 1, then at least two of them are at distance $\frac{1}{n}$ or less.

For example $m_3=10$ means that if you choose 10 points inside an equilateral triangle with sides 1 then at least two of them are at distance $\frac{1}{3}$ or less.

Hint : The equilateral triangle of side 1 can be divided into 4 equilateral triangle of sides $\frac{1}{2}$. Further an equilateral triangle of side 1 can be divided into 9 equilateral triangles of sides $\frac{1}{3}$.

I know how to divide the equilateral triangle. For example the  equilateral triangle of side 1 can be divided into 4 equilateral triangle of sides $\frac{1}{2}$ as

[image]

I am guessing that the answer if $m_n=n^2+1$. I have a vague idea of the proof. But there are quite a few loose ends. Help please!

Comment: With such problems, you have to show two things. You first have to prove that your conjecture holds, and then you have to show a construction so that nothing smaller than your conjecture holds.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you are interested in the situations where $n$ is an integer, but part of my solution will apply to non-integer $n$ as well.

Thinking about regular arrangements of regular triangles forming a larger regular triangle, it is easy to see that for $n=1$, you can place $r_1=3$ points so that the minimal distance is $1$. For $n=2$ you have $r_2=6$ corresponding to the vertices in the picture in your question, and for $n=3$ you have $r_3=10$ which looks like the example equation you gave. These are the [triangle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), with a slight index shift, for which there is a nice formula (although not quite so simple as the formula you gave):

$$r_n=\binom{n+2}{2} = \frac12n^2+\frac32n$$

Intuition might tell you that if you were to remove one point from such a regular configuration, then you have more room, thus allowing the points to shift around slightly in order to increase their minimal distance above that $1/n$. However, that intuition turns out to be wrong, as I'll show below.

Let's rephrase your question to a packing problem. Scale everything by $2n$, and you're asking about points in a triangle of side $2n$ which are at least distance $2$ apart from one another. In the interior, being at distance $2$ means that circles of radius $1$ around the points touch, so you can also talk about unit disks which must not overlap. At the boundary, the disks may well extend beyond the triangle of side $2n$, as long as they are contained in the triangle you get from that by a parallel displacement of all the edges by $1$ unit. That displacement adds $2\sqrt3$ to the edge length (please verify).

So the question I'm going to build upon is the question of how many unit disks one can place in a triangle of size $2n+2\sqrt3$ without overlap. Note however that your question is a slightly different one, and I'll get back to that in a moment.
My favorite site for packing configurations is [Erich's Packing Center](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html). Its page on [circles in a triangle](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirintri/) describes the situation you're after. They do things the other way round: list the number of unit disks and compute the triangle size from that. But you can easily turn that relation around.

So as I said, your question is indeed slightly different: you want the *minimal* number of disks where the disks have to *touch*. Which means that if you take one disk less, then they won't have to touch, which in turn means that they would fit into a slightly smaller triangle.

Now look at the images at EPC. You'll find that the triangle size for $5$ disks is the same as for $6$. So while you could place $r_2=6$ points so that they are at least $1/2$ apart, you can't place $5$ points so that they are *strictly more* than that apart. You'll have to go down to $4$ points to achieve that. Therefore, $m_2=5$ which is not the same as the $r_2=6$ discussed above. The same holds for $n=3$: the same configuration which is used for $10$ disks is already used for $9$ disks, while $8$ disks fit into a smaller triangle. Therefore $m_3=9$.

For $n=4$, the situation appears to be the same at first glance: $14$ disks take the same amount of space than $15$ disks, while $13$ fit into a smaller triangle. But there is something interesting to note here: the configurations for $13$ and $14$ disks are only described as “found”, not “proved”. So they might not be the optimal solutions yet. For the $13$-disk arrangement, we don't have to care whether there is an even smaller one, as long as we know it to be smaller than for $14$. But we have no proof that you can't place $14$ disk into a triangle which is smaller than that for $15$ disks.

I'm not sure what is known past the end of that list. One could conjecture that the pattern holds: taking one disk out of a regular configuration maintains its size, while taking out two disks reduces the size. The latter can probably be proven by looking at how the 13-disk configuration looks, and applying the same modification to the two bottom-most rows to larger situations. I have no clue how to prove the other half.

So my conjecture would be

$$m_n = r_n-1 = \binom{n+2}{2} - 1 = \frac12n^2+\frac32n$$